# MCU heating up in high-voltage circuit

Tags: ground, h-bridge, isolation, flyback, debugging

I have been facing a major issue on my board. The board is about Vin that is 4.5 V, and Vout is 100 V using a flyback converter, H-bridge inverter high-voltage mux.

STM32 is used for multiple MOSFET switching and other stuff.
Here is schematics:

*High voltage generation circuit*
[image: High voltage generation circuit]

*MCU circuit*
[image: MCU circuit]

*Overall block in schematic*
[image: Overall block in schematic]

After running the firmware for 30 minutes, the STM32 IC gets damaged. I have been observing the IC is getting heated up after a few minutes.

Probable reason is that ground handling is not right.

Can anyone help me find the root cause?

---

I also connected MCU's VDD1V2 (1.2V) pins with 3.3V.

Issue noticed so far, MCU is heating too much. And damaged couple of IC.

Comment: Sorry guys, Here is two image of main circuits. Please help me if possible. MCU getting heating up after few minutes. I damaged two ICs and still trying to figure out issue.
High voltage generation circuit - https://imgur.com/ZpKiYwC 
MCU circuit - https://imgur.com/lnBJenB 
Overall block in schematic - https://imgur.com/mwd2DfT

Comment: How much current does the MCU consume?

Comment: @winny Board consumes around 0.220A without any firmware loaded into it. And the current value rose to 0.326A after 40 min supply.

Comment: @ocrdu Added the schematic above.

Comment: Good. How much does just the MCU consume?

Comment: The flyback transformer isn't rated for 550 kHz operation.

Comment: I have been working on a SMT32H747 MCU based HV PCB board. The power supply pins of MCU is only supplied with 3.3V (max can supply 3A). Moreover, I also connected MCU's VDD1V2 (1.2V) pins with 3.3V.

Issue noticed so far, MCU is heating too much. And damaged couple of IC.

Note - MCU is not loaded with any firmware, still heats up. I'm suspecting short circuit on power supply pins of MCU.

Can anyone help me finding short circuit nets here? Also provide me your suggestions. 

MCU Power supply section image (Sorry for confusing schematic net names) https://imgur.com/U8ChMLy

Comment: _"I also connected MCU's VDD1V2 (1.2V) pins with 3.3V"_ Then it's toast. Unsolder, throw away and replace with a new one.

Comment: @winny Thanks you very much, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [data sheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32h747ag.pdf) I found, you are not supposed to connect VDD12DSI to 3.3V, but to VCAPDSI (pin 101). See note 3 on page 97.

Also, on page 140 you can find the specified rating, min=1.15V, typical=1.20V, max=1.26V. (Thanks to [VelVel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/301846/velvel) to point that out.)

Comment: Also, on page 140 you can find the specified max rating: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF8a2.png

Comment: Thanks you very much guys, appreciate your help.

Comment: The recommended way to say "Thank you" is to mark the best answer. ;-).

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to pinpoint the problem without actually having the problem in hand but here is my guess:

1. The high voltage circuit generates heat. This heat is transferred to the PCB's ground plane.
2. The ground plane heats up.
3. As thermal dissipation is approximately proportional to the temperature difference (your IC can dissipate X Watt per degree Celsius), the STM32 heats up more before dissipating the same thermal energy.

I see multiple solutions how you could solve this:

1. Split the ground plane so that the plane heats up less around the STM32.
2. Add some sort of heatsink to the STM32. The easiest option is to have some copper band going from the IC's top to some metal.

As you know your board best, does this sound plausible to you?

Comment: Thanks @mlx11 Really appreciate your comments!!

Grounding - High volt ground and Low volt grounds are isolating. I am reading 0.5V potential difference between grounds. 

I think possible next todo - Remove all resistors of HV circuit that are directly going into MCU. and test the MCU performance.

Comment: yes, testing the mcu circuit on its own and see if the problem persists would definitely help to pinpoint the problem. Alternatively it would also be interesting to know the temperature of the MCU footprint (without the MCU soldered) when the HV circuit is running.

Comment: I have been working on a SMT32H747 MCU based HV PCB board. The power supply pins of MCU is only supplied with 3.3V (max can supply 3A). Moreover, I also connected MCU's VDD1V2 (1.2V) pins with 3.3V.

Issue noticed so far, MCU is heating too much. And damaged couple of IC.

Note - MCU is not loaded with any firmware, still heats up. I'm suspecting short circuit on power supply pins of MCU.

Can anyone help me finding short circuit nets here? Also provide me your suggestions. 

MCU Power supply section image (Sorry for confusing schematic net names) https://imgur.com/U8ChMLy